# Drawing vertical/oblique lines in Metrical tree (tikz-qtree, tipa)

Tags: forest, tikz-qtree, tipa, qtree

I'm new here and I only recently started to use LaTeX.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Notice the vertical lines and the oblique lines. Vertical lines represent headedness.

This is what I'm able to do:

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=100pt}}
\Tree
[.Pwd [.Ft [.$\sigma$ [.æ ] ] [.$\sigma$ [.l ] [.\textipa{\textschwa} ] ] ] [.Ft [.$\sigma$ [.b ] [. æ ] ] [.$\sigma$ [.m ] [.\textipa{\textschwa} ]] ] ]

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I have a new problem concerning this issue:

[image]

I would like the 'á' to be aligned with the mora ($\mu$), the syllable ($\sigma$), the Foot (Ft) and the Prosodic word (Pwd). The 's' should be on the left (like it right now) but without going over.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=0, inner sep=0.8mm, l=0, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north} 
[Pwd [Ft, calign=first [$\sigma$, calign=center [s, tier=word ] [$\mu$ [\'a, tier=word, name=C ] ] [$\mu$, name=B] [$\mu$ [t , name=D ] ] ] [$\sigma$, name=A [$\mu$ [u, tier=word ] ] ] ] ]
\draw[-] (D.north)--(A.south);
\draw[-] (C.north)--(B.south);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider switching to `forest`, then you only need to set the appropriate `calign` keys. (`forest` has IMHO many advantages over `tikz-qtree` and is based on `tikz`, so you can use all `tikz` stuff, too.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south,where level={1}{calign=first}{calign=last}}
[Pwd 
 [Ft 
  [$\sigma$ 
   [\ae ] 
  ] 
  [$\sigma$ 
   [l ] 
   [\textipa{\textschwa} 
   ] 
  ] 
 ] 
 [Ft 
  [$\sigma$ 
   [b ] 
   [\ae ] 
  ] 
  [$\sigma$ 
   [m ] 
   [\textipa{\textschwa} 
   ]
  ] 
 ] 
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make lines meet (and touch) at every node with Forest? I have tried to use it but could not figure this one out.

Comment: @Scharl Sure, just add `parent anchor=south`. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

It is not so difficult with TI*k*Z's `matrix`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,nodes={minimum width=.8cm}] {%
    & & & & PWd & &\\[2em]
    Ft & & & & Ft & &\\[2em]
    $\sigma$ & & $\sigma$ & & $\sigma$ & & $\sigma$\\[2em]
    \`\ae & l & \textipa{\textschwa} & b & \'\ae & m & \textipa{\textschwa}\\
};
\draw (m-2-1.north) -- (m-1-5.south) -- (m-2-5.north);
\draw (m-3-1.north) -- (m-2-1.south) -- (m-3-3.north);
\draw (m-3-5.north) -- (m-2-5.south) -- (m-3-7.north);
\draw (m-4-1.north) -- (m-3-1.south);
\draw (m-4-2.north) -- (m-3-3.south) -- (m-4-3.north);
\draw (m-4-4.north) -- (m-3-5.south) -- (m-4-5.north);
\draw (m-4-6.north) -- (m-3-7.south) -- (m-4-7.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]